# Callback function on launching app from notification with Cordova and Urban Airship

Tags: cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

Slightly confused. I've got Urban Airship up and running with notifications and my Cordova app.

What I want to know is if there's a way to determine if the app was in the foreground or the background when the notification was pressed or received.

Maybe this isn't even a Urban Airship thing, maybe it's just determining the application state when a notification comes through?

Anyway, a bit confused and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a mix of determining the application state and calling the right Urban Airship function, this is how I got it working:

```
document.addEventListener('resume', function() {
    UAirship.getLaunchNotification(true, onLaunchedFromPush);
});

function onLaunchedFromPush(event) {
    //Do whatever you want in here
};
```